# Error loading OBJ with Texture UVs

Tags: three.js

I'm getting errors with Three.js *v68* when I load a OBJ file and use a Material with texture map in it,

```
Error: WebGL: drawElements: bound vertex attribute buffers do not have sufficient size for given indices from the bound element array
```

The mesh works fine until I add a texture map. The map is set on the material with this code:

```
var imgTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "assets/tex01.png" );
imgTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
imgTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
imgTexture.needsUpdate = true;
...
mat.map = imgTexture;
mat.needsUpdate = true;
```

The obj (exported from 3dmax) has UV data inside, and that UV info is loaded in thee faceVertexUvs property.

```
vt 0.8586 0.4138 0.0000
vt 0.8719 0.3913 0.0000
vt 0.9145 0.2598 0.0000
....
```

The mesh is loaded with THREE.OBJLoader. The loaded Object has faces: Array[6812] elements and   faceVertexUvs: Array[1].Array[6812] elements of real UVs values. So its appears to have loaded the right data. But its failing during rendering.

Comment: Are you rendering first, and then later adding a texture?

Comment: @WestLangley  yes, I'm changing the material, but I'm calling     `object.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;` and `object.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;` after change the material.

Comment: 1. Then you need to explain that in your post. 2. Try removing `imgTexture.needsUpdate = true;`

Comment: @WestLangley You hint the solution, adding `geometry.dynamic = true;` solved the problem.

Comment: The current version is r.68. What version are using and [how old is it](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases)?